# phonegap application for iPhone does not starts from Home page when app starts

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am new for objective-c but have created an iPhone Phonegap application which is working fine.
But the problem is when i start my app or click on my app icon, the app starts from the page from which(the last) i have left the app or i pressed the menu button.

The app runs first time properly (starts from splash screen and all) and from second time it doesn't start from splash screen and home page.

I dont understand why its happing like this.(Runs properly on simulator)

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You app does not really close, and will just continue from it last know state.

If you want your app to be closed when it gets pushed to the background add the `Application does not run in background` to the `info.plist` and set its value to `YES`

Comment: hey rckoenes...thanks for answer....
but got one more problem...sometimes it starts from home page(1st page) fine and sometimes it again opens from last page from where i left the app, the app is still unpredictable for me.
I dont understand why so...